# Wordpress hosted on subfolder of domain causing customizer to constantly refresh and is requesting jquery from root domain

Tags: directory

So I have wordpress installed in a subfolder of my domain: https://example.com/blog

To do this I am reverse proxying ngnix (main app) to apache (wordpress server) and everything is going great.

One weird problem I noticed though is when I go to the customizer it keeps refreshing constantly.  It looks like its trying to request jquery from the root https://example.com even though:

Site Address (URL)
WordPress Address (URL)

Are both set to: https://example.com/blog

Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked it isn't hardcoded? What's the exact error message with the full URL being requested? Is there a reason you proxy to Apache instead of just adding a `server` block for WP to the nginx rules and handling WP directly from Nginx?

Comment: Where would I check to see it isn't hardcoded?

Comment: "Is there a reason you proxy to Apache instead of just adding a server block for WP to the nginx rules and handling WP directly from Nginx?" The wordpress instance is on another vm.  I would need to move them to the same machine to have ngnix also handle wp right?

Comment: You'd look in the source code files under `wp-content` and in `wp-config.php` for it, e.g. search in folder for "XYZ.ABC/..etc`